# How can I copy a BLOB from a parameter to a local variable in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, blob

I have an Oracle PL/SQL routine that takes a BLOB as a parameter.  The BLOB contains a .jpg file.  I want to assign the BLOB parameter to a local variable.  I then want to insert (or update) a BLOB column in a table the BLOB varaible.

I have tried something like this:

```
declare
  vATTACHMENT blob;
begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(vATTACHMENT, false, dbms_lob.session);
  dbms_lob.write(vATTACHMENT, dbms_lob.lobmaxsize, 1, :pATTACHMENT)); 

  -- do some stuff

  insert into attachments (attachment, file_name)
                   values (vATTACHMENT, vFILE_NAME);
end;
```

But I get the following error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 811
ORA-06512: at line 21
```

I have also tried a direct assignment like `vATTACHMENT := :pATTACHMENT;` but that doesn't want to work either.

Comment: What's the specific problem when you try a direct assignment?

Comment: Its more of a problem with the component that is executing the PL/SQL.  It thinks that anything with a colon in front of it is a parameter, so it creates a parameter name '='.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `DEFAULT` in a variable declaration to assign a value to it without using the assignment operator `:=`, e.g.:

```
declare
  vATTACHMENT blob DEFAULT :pATTACHMENT;
begin
  -- rest of your code...
```

Comment: I chose this answer because it was the simplest, and did exactly what I needed: allow me to use vATTACHMENT throughout my SQL, with only one reference to :pATTACHMENT.

Answer (score 1):

I can only get the exact error when `pAttachment` is null or empty (tested in 10.2.0.5). If it isn't, I get `ORA-21560` instead, as it doesn't like `lobmaxsize`. If I do this instead, it's OK:

```
dbms_lob.write(vATTACHMENT, dbms_lob.getlength(:pATTACHMENT), 1, :pATTACHMENT));
```

But from your comments you have some issue referencing the bind variable more than once, and for some reason I don't quite understand you can't do assignments in PL/SQL as `:=` is misinterpreted - which makes using PL/SQL at all somewhat impractical, I'd have thought. I'm a bit unclear if you're running this as an anonymous block directly from your client; if so maybe you should consider making it a stored procedure to avoid both those issues? You could then just do:

```
vATTACHMENT := :pATTACHMENT;
```

... though then it would be a parameter passed to the procedure rather than a bind variable, and you wouldn't need to both with the copy in the first place (as Dave Costa suggests).

If you are stuck with running it like this you could incur a context switch and do:

```
select :pATTACHMENT into vATTACHMENT from dual;
```

But that's not ideal; if you just want to make a copy, why aren't you using the [copy procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i997674)?

```
dbms_lob.copy(vATTACHMENT, :pATTACHMENT, dbms_lob.getlength(:pATTACHMENT));
```

... which like that still breaks your re-referencing-bind-variables restriction, but this one does understand `lobmaxsize`:

```
dbms_lob.copy(vATTACHMENT, :pATTACHMENT, dbms_lob.lobmaxsize);
```

You'll still get an error (ORA-22994 I think) if `:pATTACHMENT` is empty or null, so you'll need to make sure it isn't before calling the block, or check inside.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Many of my issues arise from my environment.  I am using a TADOCommand in Delphi 7.  I was attempting to craft the PL/SQL to accomodate for some idiosyncracies of that component.  Also, I _did_ try dbms_lob.copy (before I saw your answer), but I must have had the parameters wrong, because I couldn't get that to work either. +1 for the detailed info in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth parameter to `DBMS_LOB.WRITE` is supposed to be either a `RAW` or a `VARCHAR2`.  If I understand you correctly, you're binding an existing `BLOB` to the `:pATTACHMENT` placeholder, so you're passing an incorrect type.

Why do you need to assign it to a temporary BLOB at all?  It seems to me that this should work:

```
insert into attachments (attachment, file_name)
               values (:pATTACHMENT, vFILE_NAME);
```

For instance, this runs fine:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE insert_blob( p_blob BLOB) IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t_dave (b) VALUES (p_blob);
  END;
BEGIN
  insert_blob( empty_blob() );
END;
/
```

Comment: The direct insert does work, but because of the components that I am working with, I can't reference the :pATTACHMENT parameter more than once in the PL/SQL, so I want to copy it's value to a local variable.  Then I can reference it as often as needed.